# Google Cloud Run Liveness Probe with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm willing to make sure that my Google Cloud Run instances that crash are known as crashed and taken care of by spawning new instances. It doesn't seem to be the case right now with my configuration.

I've read in the official Cloud Run doc [1](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks) that it was possible to configure a liveness probe to know when my container is down and then auto-heal in case of problem.

The liveness probe doesn't seem to be configurable from terraform.

Had you have any case where you had to configure it from terraform?

Thanks a lot for your answers and advice!

PS: if my question seems odd, please do not hesitate to tell me if there's another way to get auto-healing on a google cloud run instance.

PS2: what I'm thinking now right now is setting up a cloud function that will check every 10 seconds if my /health endpoint is ok, and if not, will redeploy. Let me know what you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to configure health/live probes with Terraform right now.

There is a open issue here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/12532

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Cloud Run liveness probe with Terraform using

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service

Example: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#example-usage---cloud-run-service-probes

-

With regards to the cloud_run specific module, at this writting is not possible to do so, however there is a github issue and a PR already going on so it is very likely to be ready in short.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-cloud-run/pull/120